# Laravel 5.7 - How can I dynamically trigger a user verification email?

Tags: php, laravel

When I register using the registration page, the link in the email that I get works fine.

When I instead use `$user->sendEmailVerificationNotification()`
like I saw in `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Listeners\SendEmailVerificationNotification.php`, it does not work.

I get the email, but when I click on the verify link, I get redirected to the login page and the user does not get verified.

Use Case: My system has a superuser, who can add users, and I am hoping to fire that email for the users to verify themselves.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for including the Laravel version - that is important information that I used to construct my answer.

Comment: Shouldn't you login to avoid your address to be verified by a random person ?

Comment: The link uses a signed URL.  It cannot be verified by a random person.

Answer (score 4):

**This answer assumes you've already setup Laravel's [Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication) and [Email Verification](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/verification).**

When a user registers on the application, the controller by default is using the `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUser` trait. Notice the additional functionality that takes place in the `register()` method there, and also notice that a `\Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered` [event](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/events) is generated which in turns triggers the [listener](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/events#defining-listeners) `SendEmailVerificationNotification` (where you are currently getting your code from.)

For your custom class, you could potentially reuse the `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUser` trait on it, but that could feel strange as your class is probably not a controller and the trait involves extra controller-specific logic.

Instead, you could try ripping some code from `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUser::register()` and use it within your new class.

So, something similar to:

```
// If you do not yet have a new user object.
$user = \App\User::create([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::make($data['password']),
]);

// Fire the event now with the user you want to receive an email.
event(new \Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered($user));
```

More information:

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/events

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I did try as you suggested, and I did receive the email.  However, the signedURL link did not verify the user, it just redirected the user to the login page.

Comment: I ended up having to roll my own solution.  It's unfortunate, but I was spending too much time trying to figure out what I was missing.  Thanks again for the assistance.

Comment: @jabdefiant mind sharing your custom colution? I've run into the same issue, that it redirects user to the login page.

Comment: I had to create my own mailable, and then trigger it in a new controller when the admin registers a user E.g. `Mail::to($user->email)->send(new myVerifyMail($user, 'Verify Email Address'));`  The mailable creates a signed URL, and the the view had to include this link for the user to click on.
This may not be the best way of dealing with this, but I had already wasted too much time on this issue.